# Knockout Js and Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, typeahead.js

[image]

Hello Knockout /typeahead experts, I am getting suggestion from typeahead js as above. I am supplying data in array format

```
var itemsRandom= ['Apple', 'Ball','Ape'];
```

My code for binding is the standard binding that I found here in stackoverflow. I am binding to the textbox as

```
<input type="text" data-bind="typeahead:itemsRandom,value: selectedItem">
```

**Data is not even binding to the knockout js. Suggestion is highly appreciated.**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.typeahead = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
                return function findMatches(q, cb) {
                    var matches, substringRegex;

                    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
                    matches = [];

                    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
                    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

                    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
                    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
                    $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
                        // console.log(str);
                        if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                            // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                            // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info

                            matches.push({
                                value: str
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    cb(matches);
                };
            };
            var $element = $(element);
            var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var source = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var items = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings.items) || 4;

            var valueChange = function (item) {
                allBindings.value(item);
                return item;
            };
            debugger;
            $element.attr("autocomplete", "off")
                    .typeahead({
                            hint: true,
                            highlight: true,
                            minLength: 0,
                            selectable: 'Typeahead-selectable'
                    }, {
                            valueKey: 'value',
                            source: substringMatcher(source),
                            items: items,
                            updater: valueChange
                    });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind autocomplete with KO, I removed updater in the above code and use as below

```
  var updateValues = function (val) {
                allBindings.value(val);
            };
          //  debugger;
            $element.attr("autocomplete", "off")
                    .typeahead({
                            hint: true,
                            highlight: true,
                            minLength: 0,

                    }, {
                        source: substringMatcher(source),
                        items: allBindings,
                        displayKey: 'value',
                        limit:100

                    }).on('typeahead:selected', function (el, item) {
                        updateValues(item.value);
                    }).on('typeahead:autocompleted', function (el, item) {
                        updateValues(item.value);
                    });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest version of typehead i.e 0.11, then instead of

```
valueKey: 'value',
```

use

```
displayKey: 'value',
```